# In R, how to add a column named "starts" to a data frame mathcing numeric bins at the start of each row?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, binning, startswith

In R, I want to add a column named "starts" to a data frame indicating the numeric bin at the start of each row. The remaining bins in that same row should not be included, which might be the key to fixing the code given below.

The bins are:

- ones (numbers 1-9) to be encoded as 0
- tens (10-19) to be encoded as 1
- twenties (20-29) to be encoded as 2
- thirties (30-39) to be encoded as 3
- forties (40-49) to be encoded as 4

For example:

- If the row starts with 3 numbers in the range 0-9, like: 1 3 5 16 34 43, there should be 000 in the starts column, because the row starts with 3 "ones".
- If the row starts with 12, 16, 32, 42, 45, 47 there  should be 11 in the starts column;
- If the row starts 32, 36, 30, 42, 45, 48, the starts column shall hold the string 333.
  I know that the individual functional pieces of the code work by themselves, my problem is that I cannot figure how to modify them when they are in the for-loop with the nested if-else statement.
  To test the code, I created the following example data frame:

```
n1 <- c(1, 7); n2 <- c(2, 11); n3 <- c(10, 14); n4 <- c(23, 32); n5 <- c(37, 37); n6 <- c(45, 41)
x <- data.frame(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6)
x
  n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6
1  1  2 10 23 37 45
2  7 11 14 32 37 41
```

```
#starts <- character(nrow(x)) # might be helpful to convert to string

for(i in nrow(x)){

  # match the numbers at the start of the row
  ones <- grep("^[0-9]$", x)
  tens <- grep("^[1][0-9]$", x)
  twenties <- grep("^[2][0-9]$", x)
  thirties <- grep("^[3][0-9]$", x)
  forties <- grep("^[4][0-9]$", x)

  # classifying starts
  # using rep() to return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 times the length of ones, tens, twenties, thirties or forties, respectfully and paste() with collapes="", to paste as string:

  if(any(ones)){
    x[i]$starts <- paste(rep("0", each=length(ones)), collapse="")
  } else if(any(tens)){
    x[i]$starts <- paste(rep("1", each=length(tens)), collapse="")
  } else if(any(twenties)){
    x[i]$starts <- paste(rep("2", each=length(twenties)), collapse="")
  } else if(any(thirties)){
    x[i]$starts <- paste(rep("3", each=length(thirties)), collapse="")
  } else if(any(forties)){
    x[i]$starts <- paste(rep("4", each=length(forties)), collapse="")
  } else(stop("error"))
}

x # print x
```

I expect the output to be:

```
 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 starts
1  1  2 10 23 37 45 00
2  7 11 14 32 37 41 0
```

But the program just prints the "Error: error" message from the last line of the if-else statement.
I guess, this is because in the above code, the lines with the grep command match not only the numbers at the beginning of the row but all remaining numbers till the end, if the regular expression returns a match. So, the if-else statement just cascades down to the last else(stop("error")) condition.
*The approaches and the solutions given below are better than mine, but I would also like to know why my solution doesn't work and can it be fixed.*

Comment: why your `starts` value is `000` and `00` when you have only 2 and 1 value in both the rows. Shouldn't it be `00` and `0` ?

Comment: you are correct

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
x$starts <- apply(x, 1, function(r) {
  n <- floor(r / 10)
  r <- rle(n)
  paste0(rep(r$values[1], r$lengths[1]), collapse = '')
})

x
##   n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 starts
## 1  1  2 10 23 37 45     00
## 2  7 11 14 32 37 41      0
## 3 21 25 24 29 45 78   2222
## 4 66 67 68 69 69 68 666666
```

Answer (score 0):

New data with more varied results:

```
x<-structure(list(n1 = c(1, 7, 60), n2 = c(2, 11, 62), n3 = c(10, 
  14, 66), n4 = c(23, 32, 67), n5 = c(37, 37, 68), n6 = c(45, 41, 
  69)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

x$starts<-lapply(
                 lapply(strsplit(apply(x,1, function(y) 
                                            paste0(y%/%10,collapse=""))
                                 ,""),
                         rle), 
                  function(a) paste0(rep(a$values[1],a$lengths[1]),collapse=""))

x

  n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 starts
1  1  2 10 23 37 45     00
2  7 11 14 32 37 41      0
3 60 62 66 67 68 69 666666
```

I put it all into one row, but basically what it does is calculate the full three digits, and then only takes the first digit for as many times as it is repeated.

Just for fun, I compared my code with @alko989 on a ~1800 row long dataset. Mine is marginally faster, probably because I forego the use of `floor`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
 alko 74.08931 83.40157 99.1486 88.61729 116.0893 166.8620   100
  iod 71.12178 78.14680 94.3105 84.97214 111.4073 156.0593   100
```

Comment: This does not work now and it only looks at the first 3 values, what if there are 4 values in twenties in a row?

Comment: Oh, I thought OP only wanted first three... I see what you mean.

Comment: Fixed it. Note that this code will not work if x already has the starts column, because then the numbers will become non-numeric (i.e., strings) when `apply` is used.